# Run Docker Containers without having a logged in User on Windows

Tags: docker, windows

Is it possible to run Docker containers without being logged in as a user on Windows?  I have a few containers I am auto-deploying on a server, but I am currently stuck leaving a generic service account logged in so that the containers run and the docker daemon stays running.

My current setup works, but I feel like there must be a better way to deploy/run than to always have an account logged in.

**Setup**

- Windows Server 2012 and 2016
- No docker-desktop because of nested virtualization scenario requirement
- Linux not an option due to business requirements

Comment: Did you create a Windows Scheduled task? In that service it is possible to click one 'user should not be logged on'. Does that work and would it be an option?

Comment: @030 The Windows Scheduled task still needed a user to login.  The only way I've managed to get this to work is using Docker Windows, not the toolbox.  The only thing I've found is a third party tool: https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/StartDockerDaemonAsAWindowsService.html

Comment: Could you post an answer?

Comment: @030: I haven't found a non-commercial solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Docker can be set to run as a service, that should bypass the need to log in with a service account:

1. `dockerd.exe --register-service`
2. `net start Docker`
3. `sc config Docker start=auto`

[Dockerd.exe](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27696)